# Oracle SQL Regex Matching two fields

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have two tables in oracle sql with a field in each that I need to match and display if it is not matching. The two fields in the separate tables have various ways of being formatted which is not ideal, but is the situation. Example:

Table 1:

| ID | EXAMPLE_STRING | EXAMPLE_REGEX_MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (0888DY:A001:B2:C3) | A1B2C3 |
| 2 | (0888DY:A001:B3) | A1B3 |

Table 2:

| ID | EXAMPLE_STRING | EXAMPLE_REGEX_MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0888DY,A1:B2:C3 | A1B2C3 |
| 2 | 0888DY,A1:B2 | A1B2 |

In the above case I want ID 1 to match across tables and be ignored and ID 2 to be selected because it is not matching to each other. The determination of matching is just A followed by a nonzero, B followed by any nonzero, C followed by any nonzero, etc so in ID 1's case: A1B2C3. Everything else like the prefix 0888DY, commas, parenthesis, leading zeroes ideally would be ignored. I assume I need to use regular expressions to do this so here is my start:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.EXAMPLE_STRING, b.EXAMPLE_STRING
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE REGEX_REPLACE(a.EXAMPLE_STRING, regexhere) != REGEX_REPLACE(b.EXAMPLE_STRING, regexhere)
```

Comment: Does `0888DY` prefix matter to the match or non-match logic too?

Comment: You can't use `REGEXP_INSTR()` for this. It returns the position where the regexp matches. That's not useful for telling if the pattern match is the same in two strings.

Comment: "Does 0888DY prefix matter to the match or non-match logic too? " No. Only the letters A-C and the number after them have to match. I'm just having trouble making the regex ignore everything but those variables for the matching.

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_INSTR()` is not useful to tell if two strings match the same pattern. It just returns the position where the pattern match is found (just as `INSTR()` does with a plain string).

In order to turn `A001` into `A1` you'll need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` along with a capture group so you can remove the leading zeroes.

You also need to remove everything before the first `:` or `,` before comparing.

```
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(a.EXAMPLE_STRING, '^[^,:]*', ''), '[,:]([[:alpha:]])0*([[:digit:]]+)', '\1\2') != REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(b.EXAMPLE_STRING, '^[^,:]*', ''), '[,:]([[:alpha:]])0*([[:digit:]]+)', '\1\2')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the matching pattern you mentioned... I am not sure why I can't understand it. The way you described,

> The determination of matching is just A followed by a nonzero, B
> followed by any nonzero, C followed by any nonzero

this should also not match the row 1 of table 1 because A is followed by some zeros, but in table 2 it's not the case.

So I need more explanation if this answer doesn't help you.

As you mentioned:

> The two fields in the separate tables have various ways of being
> formatted which is not ideal

An idea would be to ***try normalizing these 2 fields***, so that the ones that don't match with each other. Check this out:

```
-- CTEs to normalize the strings 
--and REGEXP_REPLACE to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from EXAMPLE_STRING
WITH NormalizedTable1 AS (
  SELECT ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(EXAMPLE_STRING, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', '') AS NormalizedString
  FROM Table1
),
NormalizedTable2 AS (
  SELECT ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(EXAMPLE_STRING, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', '') AS NormalizedString
  FROM Table2
)
-- Finally, join the normalized tables and select non-matching records
SELECT t1.ID, t1.EXAMPLE_STRING AS Table1String, t2.EXAMPLE_STRING AS Table2String
FROM NormalizedTable1 t1
INNER JOIN NormalizedTable2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.NormalizedString != t2.NormalizedString;
```

You should choose your RegEx for normalization very carefully, to avoid surprises.

As I said, I couldn't really understand that part of your question, so my RegEx probably **won't** be an exact fix to your problem

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for this response. This is very close to what I want. Essentially I want the normalization/match to only be on the letters A-C (regardless of leading zeroes and prefix) and the nonzero number after it but before the next letter. 

(0888DY:A001:B2:C3) goes to A1B2C3
(0888DY:A001:B3) goes to A1B3
0888DY,A1:B2:C3 goes to A1B2C3
0888DY,A1:B2 goes to A1B2

Getting that regex is tricky. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a simple RegEx,. I would probably focus on dividing it into 2 parts: first remove unwanted characters and keep A,B,C and the digits, then remove the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

With the data provided and regarding your comment after M. Pour's answer ("*Essentially I want the normalization/match to only be on the letters A-C (regardless of leading zeroes and prefix) and the nonzero number after it but before the next letter*") one option could be without using regexp at all.
Create CTE that will transform your sample data to get them patternized:

```sql
WITH        --  Sample Data
    tbl_1 (ID, EXAMPLE_STRING) AS
        (   Select  1,  '(0888DY:A001:B2:C3)' From Dual Union All
        Select  2,  '(0888DY:A001:B3)' From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_2 (ID, EXAMPLE_STRING) AS
        (   Select  1,  '0888DY,A1:B2:C3' From Dual Union All
        Select  2,  '0888DY,A1:B2' From Dual 
        ),
  transformed AS
    (   Select        t1.ID, 
                    t1.EXAMPLE_STRING "T1_STRING_ORIGINAL",
                    t2.EXAMPLE_STRING "T2_STRING_ORIGINAL",
                    Replace(SubStr( Replace(Replace(Replace(t1.EXAMPLE_STRING, '(', ''), ')', ''), ',', ':')
                          , InStr(Replace(Replace(Replace(t1.EXAMPLE_STRING, '(', ''), ')', ''), ',', ':') || ':', ':', 1, 1) + 1 ), ':', '') "T1_TO_MATCH",  
                    -- 
                    Replace(SubStr( Replace(Replace(Replace(t2.EXAMPLE_STRING, '(', ''), ')', ''), ',', ':')
                          , InStr(Replace(Replace(Replace(t2.EXAMPLE_STRING, '(', ''), ')', ''), ',', ':') || ':', ':', 1, 1) + 1 ), ':', '') "T2_TO_MATCH"
        From            tbl_1 t1
        Inner Join  tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.ID = t1.ID)
    ),
--
--  Result for transformed CTE
--
--          ID T1_STRING_ORIGINAL  T2_STRING_ORIGI T1_TO_MATCH    T2_TO_MATCH      
--  ---------- ------------------- --------------- -------------- -----------------
--           1 (0888DY:A001:B2:C3) 0888DY,A1:B2:C3 A001B2C3       A1B2C3           
--           2 (0888DY:A001:B3)    0888DY,A1:B2    A001B3         A1B2
```

**NOTE:** Above code removes characters not needed for further processing, such as round brackets and commas and cuts off the first element. Be aware that this works with sample data provided and that, if there are some other such characters in your real data, you may need to handle them too.
The resulting dataset should be tuned up a bit more with another CTE and then you can get your expected result

```sql
  matches AS
    (   Select  t.ID, T1_STRING_ORIGINAL, T2_STRING_ORIGINAL, 
                Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'A') > 0 Then SubStr( t.T1_TO_MATCH, 1, InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'A')) End|| 
                  Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'A') > 0 Then CAST(SubStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'A') + 1, Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B') > 0 Then InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B') Else 9999 End - InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'A') - 1) as Number DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) End ||
                Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B') > 0 Then SubStr( t.T1_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B'), 1) End || 
                  Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B') > 0 Then CAST(SubStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B') + 1,  Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C') > 0 Then InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C') Else 9999 End - InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'B') - 1) as Number DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) End || 
                Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C') > 0 Then SubStr( t.T1_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C'), 1) End || 
                  Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C') > 0 Then CAST(SubStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C') + 1) as Number DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR)  End
                "T1_TO_MATCH",
                --
                Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'A') > 0 Then SubStr( t.T2_TO_MATCH, 1, InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'A')) End|| 
                  Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'A') > 0 Then CAST(SubStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'A') + 1,  Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B') > 0 Then InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B') Else 9999 End - InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'A') - 1) As Number DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) End ||
                Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B') > 0 Then SubStr( t.T2_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B'), 1) End || 
                  Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B') > 0 Then CAST(SubStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B') + 1,  Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'C') > 0 Then InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'C') Else 9999 End - InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'B') - 1) as Number DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) End || 
                Case When InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'C') > 0 Then SubStr( t.T2_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'C'), 1) End || 
                  Case When InStr(t.T1_TO_MATCH, 'C') > 0 Then CAST(SubStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, InStr(t.T2_TO_MATCH, 'C') + 1) as Number DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) End
                "T2_TO_MATCH"
         From   transformed t 
    )    
--
--  Result for matches CTE
--
--          ID T1_STRING_ORIGINAL  T2_STRING_ORIGI T1_TO_MATCH          T2_TO_MATCH         
--  ---------- ------------------- --------------- -------------------- --------------------
--           1 (0888DY:A001:B2:C3) 0888DY,A1:B2:C3 A1B2C3               A1B2C3              
--           2 (0888DY:A001:B3)    0888DY,A1:B2    A1B3                 A1B2     

--  M a i n   S Q L           
SELECT  ID, T1_STRING_ORIGINAL, T2_STRING_ORIGINAL
FROM    matches
WHERE T1_TO_MATCH != T2_TO_MATCH
--
--  R e s u l t :
--
--          ID T1_STRING_ORIGINAL  T2_STRING_ORIGINAL
--  ---------- ------------------- ------------------
--           2 (0888DY:A001:B3)    0888DY,A1:B2
```

If this could be adjusted to work with your actual data - it should be significantly faster then regexp.